Tensor product of irreps projected onto fields
Some background:
I am trying to build a potential which consists of the $\varphi_i$ fields, which are $SU(2)$ doublets (if relevant). The form of the scalar potential should be
$$
V(\varphi) = A_{ij}\,\varphi_i^\dagger \varphi_j + B_{ijkl}\,\varphi_i^\dagger \varphi_j \varphi_k^\dagger \varphi_l + \text{(6 terms + 8 terms )},
$$
where $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ijkl}$ are some coefficients, and there are some additional rules; but not to complicate the discussion I shall skip those.
Given some group $\mathcal{G}$ with generators $g(k)$, the transformed fields are
$$\varphi_i^\prime  = g(k)_{ij} \varphi_j,$$
So then it is possible to solve
$$V(\varphi) - V(\varphi^\prime) = 0,$$
in terms of the coefficients $\{A_{ij},~B_{ijkl},~\dots\, \}$ to get $V(\varphi)$ invariant under $G$. This is how I was doing it.

Question:
Now, I want to understand how to do this in terms of the irreducible representations and am having some difficulties by representing different irreps in terms of invariant combinations of fields (is that a correct terminology?). I understand how to construct tensor products using the character tables, but get completely stuck how to project that onto the space of the fields $\varphi_i$.
Consider, for example, an $S_3$ group (I am trying to construct a potential symmetric under $\mathbb{Z}_7 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ but would like to understand the example in the provided article.). There is an article (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.3552) where they construct what (I believe) I am looking for, specifically eq. (41) on p.11:
$$
\begin{array} { l } { \left( \begin{array} { l } { x _ { 1 } } \\ { x _ { 2 } } \end{array} \right) _ \mathbf{2} \otimes \left( \begin{array} { c } { y _ { 1 } } \\ { y _ { 2 } } \end{array} \right) _ \mathbf{ 2 } = \left( x _ { 1 } y _ { 1 } + x _ {2} y _ { 2 } \right) _  \mathbf{1} + \left( x _ { 1 } y _ { 2 } - x _ { 2 } y _ { 1 } \right) _ \mathbf{ 1 ^ { \prime } } + \left( \begin{array} { c } { x _ { 1 } y _ { 2 } + x _ { 2 } y _ { 1 } } \\ { x _ { 1 } y _ { 1 } - x _ { 2 } y _ { 2 } } \end{array} \right) _ \mathbf{ 2 } }, \\ { \left( \begin{array} { l } { x _ { 1 } } \\ { x _ { 2 } } \end{array} \right) _ \mathbf{ 2 } \otimes \left( y ^ { \prime } \right) _ \mathbf{ 1 ^ { \prime } } = \left( \begin{array} { c } { - x _ { 2 } y ^ { \prime } } \\ { x _ { 1 } y ^ { \prime } } \end{array} \right) _ \mathbf{ 2 } }, \\ { \left( x ^ { \prime } \right) _ \mathbf{ 1 ^ { \prime } } \otimes \left( y ^ { \prime } \right) _ \mathbf{ 1 ^ { \prime } } = \left( x ^ { \prime } y ^ { \prime } \right) _ \mathbf{ 1 } }. \end{array}
$$
I understand their eq. (34), which is $(b.X) \otimes (b.Y)$, but am completely lost in what follows, i.e., eqs. (35-41).
My guess would be that since there are 3 irreps of $S_3$ one needs to construct some $(4 \times 4)$ matrices (since the standard representations of $S_3$ is a 2-dimensional) and then find 4(?) orthonormal vectors corresponding to three different representations.
Is there a simple algorithm for what I want to do with the tensor products of the irreps, like I am currently doing by solving $V(\varphi) - V(\varphi^\prime) = 0$?
P.S. Sorry if formulation of the question is wrong since I got only a basic knowledge of Group Theory.
